# Rendering HTML Tags from Server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, tinymce, text-formatting

I have a webpage containing a text editor(tinymce), which does nice formatting to the text and then stores it in the database. The server retrieves this formatted text from database and sends it to a webpage (ejs template). But HTML tags are not considered  and plain text is rendered on the webpage.

`<p style="text-align=center;">Hello,World</p>`

This p tag is stored in database and while rendering it on webpage, it is rendered as plain text, without p tag functionality. How can I render HTML content sent by server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the syntax <%- your value %>

for example:

`your_value = <p style="text-align=center;">Hello,World</p>`

if you render the value like this:

```
<%= your_value %>
```

You will get the output as text. But if you render it like this:

```
<%- your_value %>
```

you will get only "Hello,World".

Answer (score 0):

you can preserve the indentation by using the pre HTML tags. So wrap the code that you want to display online using the (< pre>pre html tags), some more documentaion on that here:
https://devpractical.com/display-html-tags-as-plain-text/